# Consequence of diffeomorphisms invariance in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, gauge-theory

Let's consider a theory with gravity and matter field(s) $\Phi$. The action of this theory is the following:
\begin{equation}
S[g,\Phi] = S_g[g]+S_m[g,\Phi] = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int_Md^4x\sqrt{-g}R+\int_Md^4x\sqrt{-g}\mathcal{L}_m[x,\Phi].
\end{equation}
The fact the the *Einstein-Hilbert* action $S_g[g]$ is invariant under diffeomorphisms implies the conservation of the *Einstein tensor* $G_{\mu\nu}$:
\begin{equation}
\delta_\xi S_g[g]=0\Longrightarrow \nabla_\mu G^{\mu\nu}=0.
\end{equation}
The fact that the matter action $S_m[g,\Phi]$ is invariant under diffeomorphism implies the conservation of the *energy-momentum tensor* $T^{\mu\nu}$:
\begin{equation}
\delta_\xi S_m[g,\Phi]=0\Longrightarrow \nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0.
\end{equation}
But in the end, isn't it the total action $S[g,\Phi]$ that is supposed to be invariant under diffeomorphisms? So could we imagine some kind of transformations where $S_g[g]$ and $S_m[g,\Phi]$ are not invariant but the sum the two is? So the transformation of the two terms would cancel each other.

Is this precisely what Einstein's equations are saying?

Comment: I think sean carroll might answer your question: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll5.html See eqtns 5.34-5.36 and the corresponding text discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matter action must be invariant under diffeomorphisms, so we have
$$
\delta_{\xi} S_M [g,\phi^{I}] = 0 = \int \frac{\delta S_M}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}}\delta g^{\mu \nu} + \int \frac{\delta S_M}{\delta \Phi^I}\delta \phi^I \ .
$$
The last term, the variation w.r.t to the matter fields, is zero if $\phi$ satisfies the matter equations of motion. Then using the definition of $T^{\mu \nu}$ and knowing to use the Lie derivative of the metric, we arrive at $\nabla^{\mu}T_{\mu \nu} = 0$ (I assume you know how to fill in those steps).

The Einstein Hilbert action $S_{EH}$ *is* diffeomorphism invariant, not just because we want it to be. You can do the calculation in full (i.e. without assuming it). So you'd need to use a different gravitational action in order to be in the situation you're describing.